# Javascript json data read problem for double quote

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I'm passing json data to javascript of Google Chart.
My json data format is

```
["Md. Aslam",170972.7,"gold"]
```

But in google chart javascript shows like

```
[&quot;JIANGSU LTD&quot;,170972.7,&quot;gold&quot;]
```

Here is showing `&quot;` in respect of `"`
I need this data with `"` as I have given. How do I solve this?

My Controller (sending from data):

```
def data1 = table.executeQuery("select name, point from table") as JSON
render(view: "/report", model: [data1: data1])
```

My report.gsp (view of google chart):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {
            google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [ 'Element', "Density", { role: "style" } ],
                    ${data1}
                ]);

                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns([0, 1,
                    { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" },
                    2]);

                var options = {
                    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
                    width: 600,
                    height: 400,
                    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
                    legend: { position: "none" },
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("ord_variation"));
                chart.draw(view, options);
        }}
    </script>
```

I'm using groovy/grails 3

Comment: Note that Java != Javascript

Comment: I know that @mark

Comment: Would you mind to share the code snippet how you passed data to Google Charts ?

Comment: I'm using groovy/grails. Here is my controller:
def data1 = table.executeQuery("select name, point from table") as JSON
render(view: "/report", model: [data1: data1])
In view i'm receiving in google charts as:
${data1}

Comment: Have you set `render(contentType:"application/json")` before rendering it as json?

Comment: Yes but same result

Comment: Please also add the relevant parts from your report.gsp.  And don't add it as comment, but edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Can you please try removing `@Resource(uri='/XXXXX')` at the top of your code? (if you have one)

Comment: I guess it was because ${data1} is a string (You passed by JSON), so Google Chart output it with HTML encoded. Could you try `JSON.parse(${data1})` ?

Comment: Also tried this but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my solution as report.gsp

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
    ${data1};
</g:applyCodec>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var j = "${data}"; // data is your json data came from controller
    var result = JSON.parse((j.split("&quot;").join('"')).split("=").join(':')); //use result object

</script>
```

Hope this will helps you